# How to prevent serialization to Json null values?

Tags: json, dart

I have got class that have `toJson` method.

```
class SearchFormModel {
  
    List<String>? purchaseNumbersList;
    List<String>? regionsSelectedNames; 
    
    SearchFormModel( {
      this.purchaseNumbersList,
      this.regionsSelectedNames
    }
    );


    Map toJson() => {
      'purchaseNumbersList': purchaseNumbersList,
      'regionsNames': regionsSelectedNames
    };

}
```

I want to prevent adding fields with `null` values to Json.

For example if `purchaseNumbersList` is `null` it should not be added to result JSON.

How to do it in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collection if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) to optionally include a key/value pair in a map literal.

```dart
class SearchFormModel {
  List<String>? purchaseNumbersList;
  List<String>? regionsSelectedNames; 
    
  SearchFormModel({
    this.purchaseNumbersList,
    this.regionsSelectedNames
  });

  Map toJson() => {
    if (purchaseNumbersList != null) 'purchaseNumbersList': purchaseNumbersList,
    if (regionsSelectedNames != null) 'regionsNames': regionsSelectedNames,
  };
}
```